# Using the Cauchy product with $\sin(x)\sinh(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find an expression for the nth non-zero term of the Maclaurin series for f(x), where $f(x)=\sin(x)\sinh(x)$

I tried to start with the Cauchy Product of the two series :

$$\begin{align}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^ix^{2i+1}}{(2k+1)!}}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}}\right)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^k{\frac{(-1)^lx^{2l+1}x^{2(k-l)+1}}{(2l+1)!(2(k-l)+1)!}}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{k}{\frac{(-1)^lx^{2(k+1)}}{(2l+1)!(2k-2l+1)!}}\end{align}$$

Providing the algebra is correct, I'm not too sure how to continue this or if I missed a trick with $f(x)$ that makes the expansion easy to find. I know some terms will be zero due to $\sin0$ in the expansion but not sure how to get around the series.

EDIT : Trying with exponentials, now fixed (thanks @jjagmaths)

$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2i}\right)&=\frac{e^{ix}e^x-e^{ix}e^{-x}-e^{-ix}e^{x}+e^{-ix}e^{-x}}{4i}\\&=\frac{e^{ix}e^{2x}-e^{ix}-e^{-ix}e^{2x}+e^{-ix}}{4ie^{x}}\\&=\frac{(e^{x(2+i)}-e^{x(2-i)})+(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})}{4ie^{x}}\\&=\frac{2ie^{2x}\sin(x)-2i\sin(x)}{4ie^{x}}\\&=\frac{i\sin(x)(e^{2x}-1)}{2ie^{x}}\\&=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\sin(x)(e^{2x}-1)\end{align}$$

Comment: Your answer looks correct. The non-zero condition probably refers to the fact that the function is even, hence all odd terms are zero.

Comment: I think Cauchy product is overkill for this task. It would be a lot easier to write $f$ in terms of exponentials first. Anyway you might find this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495752/show-that-sum-ell-0k-binom2k12-ell-22k) (using Cauchy product to find the series expansion of $\sin x\cos x$) helpful.

Comment: @user170231 I was thinking it's too overkill... but I knew it would give something at least. I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: In your try with exponentials you made a mistake: $\displaystyle\sin x = \frac{e^{i x}-e^{-ix}}{2\color{red}i}$

Comment: @jjagmath thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing:

> $$\begin{align}\sin(x)\sinh(x)&=\cdots\\&=\sum_{k\ge0}x^{2(k+1)}\sum_{\ell=0}^k(-1)^\ell\cdot\frac{1}{(2\ell+1)!(2(k-\ell)+1)!}\\&=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^{2(k+1)}}{(2(k+1))!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{2(k+1)}{2\ell+1}(-1)^\ell\\&=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^{2(k+1)}}{(2(k+1))!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{2(k+1)}{2\ell+1}i^{2\ell+1-1}\\&=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^{2(k+1)}}{(2(k+1))!}\sum_{\ell=0}^{2(k+1)}\binom{2(k+1)}{\ell}(i^\ell-(-i)^{\ell})\\&=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^{2(k+1)}}{(2(k+1))!}((1+i)^{2(k+1)}-(i^{-1}(1+i))^{2(k+1)})\\&=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^{2(k+1)}}{(2(k+1))!}(1-(-1)^{k+1})(1+i)^{2(k+1)}\\&=i^{-1}\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{x^{2(2m+1)}}{(2(2m+1))!}(1+i)^{2(2m+1)}\\&=i^{-1}\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{x^{4m+2}}{(4m+2)!}\cdot(\sqrt{2}\exp(\pi i/4))^{4m+2}\\&=i^{-1}\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{x^{4m+2}}{(4m+2)!}2^{2m+1}\exp(\pi i(m+1/2))\\&=\sum_{m\ge0}(-1)^m\cdot\frac{2^{2m+1}x^{4m+2}}{(4m+2)!}\end{align}$$

A significantly easier method, similar to the one suggested in the comments:

> $$\begin{align}\sin(x)\sinh(x)&=\Im\cosh(x+ix)\\&=\Im\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(x(1+i))^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\&=\Im\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\cdot(\sqrt{2}\exp(\pi i/4))^{2k}\\&=\Im\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\cdot2^k\exp(\pi ik/2)\\&=\Im\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{x^{2(2m+1)}}{(2(2m+1))!}\cdot2^{2m+1}\exp(\pi i(m+1/2))\\&=\sum_{m\ge0}(-1)^m\cdot\frac{2^{2m+1}\cdot x^{4m+2}}{(4m+2)!}\end{align}$$

"What's wrong here"? You forgot to divide by $i$: you wrote $\sin(x)\overset{?}{=}\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$ but actually it is $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2\color{red}{i}}$. More than that, you should have left it in exponential form! Because then all you have to do is add together the easier-to-handle (than a Cauchy product) exponential series.

You also made a mistake factorising your expression. Even after dividing by $i$, it is not true that $\sin(x)\sinh(x)\overset{?}{=}\sin(x)\cdot\frac{e^{2x}-1}{2}$ - that equation is off by a factor of exactly $e^x$ (the RHS is $e^x\sin(x)\sinh(x)$).

Comment: found the mistake, just didn't multiply the denominator by $e^{x}$ also. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AnthonyML you're welcome